# File suffix usage in Google Drive (SDK)

Tags: google-drive-api

We picked a random file suffix (.mxe) to use with our applications files in Google Drive, but we noticed that many other applications don't show a suffix and open from drive correctly.

If the user removes the suffix in the save dialog, Drive doesn't know how to open it. So, we could add this in the back-end each time, but it just looks better in the Drive listing to have no suffix.

I've got "mxe" listed as the Default File Extensions in the Drive SDK console. If I remove that, will Drive then base the decision which app to open the file with based only on the creating application ID?

If I do that, will the files with the .mxe suffix still open correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate suffixes and MIME types with your application. 
The applications that work fine with files without suffixes have registered MIME types that can be opened with them. 
For example, if you are writing an image editor, you should register `image/*` as supported MIME types and the Google Drive UI will know that images can be opened with your application.

If you are not using a standard MIME type, you can always set a custom one (e.g `application/mxe`).